# Reactive programming and SCDF Kafka stream on high load

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, apache-kafka-streams, project-reactor, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are using a SCDF Stream. It is consuming from Kafka topic via a bean that is a providing consumer. After reading topic events, we are trying to process those events like this.

```
    KafkaUtils.fluxMessage(msg)
        .parallel(10)
        .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .doOnNext(handler)
        .sequential()
        .then()
        .block();
```

Events are processing inside of doOnNext but whole process is blocked with last function.
inside of doOnNext I mean handler is doing this;

```
    notificationsProcessor
        .processEvent(event) //business logic
        .doOnNext(someFacade::store) //store processed data
        .then()
        .subscribe();
```

With this way we can never complete processEvent function(It is starting though). It is always losing thread somewhere in procesEvent. So never called store function. **This is not happening with event numbers like 10 or 20 from topic it is happening when there is a huge load like thousands per seconds.**

But when we changed to

```
    notificationsProcessor
        .processEvent(event) //business logic
        .doOnNext(someFacade::store) //store processed data
        .then()
        .block();
```

It is processing thousands of data per seconds. May someone enlighten me please? I don't understand why first one is never reaching the doOnNext in high load but reaching in small loads.

Also when we changed to

```
    notificationsProcessor
        .processEvent(event) //business logic
        .doOnNext(someFacade::store) //store processed data
        .then() //not necessary yes
        .subscribe()
    Thread.sleep(10_000)
```

it is working.

Is it possible to have bug in reactor or what is missing?
Thank you in advance. I can try to explain further our situation according to comments.